# What should i use as a server?

Tags: authentication, server, tcp

I am making an andriod app with a login screen that will store simple user info.
As a test i have used a tcp server VB.net on my home computer and am able to connect and login.

client connects
server checks client name
gets the password and if it is correct returns a session that is valid till the session is ended.

Is there a better method?
thanks

Comment: Yes, there is. Check oauth2 password grant type: https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#other-app-types

Comment: How should I go about the server? Is it worth using a web server or a tcp server on my machine?

Comment: I would forget raw tcp.. Just use an HTTP server

Comment: Would use firedatabase be good?

Comment: OR should i use a mysql?

Comment: You can use Firebase, and you will have already implemented authentication system. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?hl=en-419

Answer (score 0):

Check out Firebase for user authentication. The main advantage is that it is easy to setup and clean. It allows users to login via username/passoword, Google, Facebook, Github... etc. Check the below link to find out more.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui